# Why won't countries ban media companies that leak their own intelligence?

Tags: united-kingdom, international, media

https://thegrayzone.com/2022/06/07/paul-masons-covert-intelligence-grayzone/

> This makes me believe the work should be done by white label
> organizations operating with firm infosec - Signal/ProtonMail, clean
> phones. Just as Bellingcat get a steady stream of intel from Western
> agencies, I suspect the attacks on you and others are fed by Russian
> and Chinese intel - which will include not just hacking but electronic
> warfare and HUmINt.

Why won't countries ban media companies that leak their own intelligence? The Grayzone leaked an email from a journalist talking to a UK intelligence contractor, but the West didn't ban TheGrayzone as a result of this, is there a reason for this? Are there legal limitations that hand cuff the UK government from banning The Grayzone. Considering that Russia banned Bellingcat, I don't see why the UK government wouldn't do the same.

Comment: This is another opportunity to emphasize again that talking about the "West" presents a monolithic construct that confuses analyses like these. The United States of America, for instance, has a broader legal conception of freedom of expression than the United Kingdom, and, say, the government of Estonia may be completely uninterested in UK intelligence leaks.

Comment: "Grayzone" didn't leak anything.  If Grayzone had access to the email, it had *already* leaked.

Comment: What would "banning" a news organization look like? Given that most media organizations are entirely based on the internet, how would "banning" affect them?

Comment: FWIW, [Grayzone @ wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Grayzone)  A ban would probably lend this "news site" credibility.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "Several Supreme Court cases (e.g. Bartnicki v. Vopper) have established previously that the American Constitution protects the re-publication of illegally gained information provided the publishers did not themselves violate any laws in acquiring it."

Comment: also https://mediabiasfactcheck.com/the-grayzone/

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica - Yes, apparently they consider themselves a radical left-wing site, but a glance at the site's homepage reveals it to be full of foreign policy articles from a pro-authoritarian slant, with the only seemingly left-leaning one a headline about "technocratic forces" threatening Dutch farmers—a perspective so radically left that it could even appear in the [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/middle_east/egypts-new-cabinet-to-be-dominated-by-technocrats/2012/08/01/gJQANE8vPX_story.html) in 2012.

Comment: One might reasonably question whether a website that devotes several front-page articles to the defense of socially conservative autocrats without a single headline mentioning the revolution of the proletariat—or in modern times, at least something related to queer liberation, intersectional feminism, or some other left-oriented perspective on social issues—is particularly justified in considering itself on the left, radical or otherwise.

Comment: @Obie2.0: well, Assad is to the left of the Islamists, or something like that. I'm reminded that a US president congratulated Taraki on his coup... for advancing women's rights.

Comment: Authoritarian governments have no problem with banning websites, publishers, etc. Controlling the flow of information is highly critical for authoritarian governments. Non-authoritarian countries have a big problem with banning websites, publishers, etc. Governmental attempts to control the flow of information is highly criticized in non-authoritarian governments.

Comment: @DJClayworth Banning a news website is easy: Tell every internet provider in the country that the CEO will mysteriously die of a painful disease and that all employees will go to jail if the provider doesn't cut off all access to and from the to-be-banned website. Some customers may get around the ban by using a VPN, but that's just a few people, and VPNs also can also be banned. The reliance on the internet has made freedom of speech somewhat fragile.

Comment: @DavidHammen So you've assumed the country is a vicious tyrannical dictatorship. Since they already ban media and everybody knows it it's safe to say the question wasn't about them.

Comment: @DJClayworth The question explicitly mentions Russia. Multiple high level Russians have died under mysterious circumstances, including falls from tall buildings, radioactive poisoning, and the list goes on. Lower level Russian journalists have fled the country to avoid persecution, have gone to jail, or have died under mysterious circumstances. I think it is safe to assume the question is about tyrannical dictatorships versus non-tyrannical countries such as the UK.

Comment: @DavidHammen The question is *about* why UK (and presumably similar countries) *don't* ban media. There's no point in asking why tyrannical dictatorships like Russia *don't* ban media when they do.

Comment: @DJClayworth Reread the last sentence of the question: *Considering that Russia banned Bellingcat, I don't see why the UK government wouldn't do the same.*

Comment: Yes, you make my point exactly. The question is "Why doesn't UK ban media like Russia",, not "Why doesn't Russia ban media?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The obvious answer, in most Western countries the press has rather strong constitutional protections, which balance such things as the [Official Secrets Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Official_Secrets_Act_1989) in the UK. Most provisions of the official secrets act refer to officials, only a few refer to the press. Even if the UK government could ban the new news organization, as opposed to prosecuting individuals in it for their disclosure of intelligence, parts of the public in the UK would be highly critical of such an action.